# Add sum for records with duplicate titles

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with quantities that I needed added up for school names that are identical.  Not all school names are identical and need to be added.

My data is 3000 rows long, below is a sample of the data I have.

I need a way to automate it so that I can get a sum quantity of 629 (399+230=629) for Abilene Independent School District.  I need the sum total for all duplicate school names.

```
 **QTY  Schoolname**
+693    7th Street Elementary School
+612    Aberdeen Elementary School
+399    Abilene Ind School District
+230    Abilene Ind School District
+431    Abraham Lincoln Elem School
+630    AcadeMir Charter School West
+212    ACADEMY ADVENTURES MIDTOWN
+715    Academy Ind School District
+345    Academy Of Dover Charter Sch
+372    Addison Elementary School
+434    Advance Public School
+1,040  ADVANTAGE ACADEMY ADMIN OFFICE
+330    Agape Inc
+240    AHFACHKEE SCHOOL
+555    Aiken Co Public Schools
+480    Aiken Co Public Schools
+400    Alachua Elementary School
+309    Alamance-Burlington Sch Dist
+530    Alamo City School
+536    Alamo City School District
+280    Alamo City School District
+300    Albert Einstein Endeavor Aca
+775    Albertville City School Dist
+273    Alexander II Magnet School
+242    Alexandria City Pub Sch Dist
+600    Algonac Cmty School District
+347    Algonac Cmty School District
+241    Algonac Cmty School District
```

Comment: The data structure is two columns, one for quantity, one for school name?  Does quantity actually have a "+" (would make it text rather than a number unless you are using a special format to display it that way)?

Answer (score 1):

Select the table goto insert>pivot table.

In the pivot table select Schoolname as the row label and QTY as the value (defaults to sum).